How do I link boost in my mingw_w64 cmake setup?
This is my CMakeLists:
# Project & Executable
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29.1)
project(Madeline)

set(SOURCES
                src/Skeleton/main.cpp
                src/MCAD/Logger/Logging.cpp
)

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0")
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
find_package(Boost 1.85 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
# else()
#     message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found. Please install Boost.")
# endif()

# Update Git Modules
find_package(Git QUIET)
if(GIT_FOUND AND EXISTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git)
                option(GIT_SUBMODULE ON)
                if(GIT_SUBMODULE)
                                mesage(STATUS "Submodule update")
                                execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} submodule update --init --recursive
                                                                                                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                                                                                                RESULT_VARIABLE GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT )
                                if(NOT GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT_EQUAL "0")
                                                message(FATAL_ERROR "git submodule update --init failed with ${GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT}, please checkout submodules")
                                endif()
                endif()
endif()

if(NOT EXISTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/glfw/CMakeLists.txt")
                message(FATAL_ERROR "The glfw submodules was not downloaded! GIT_SUBMODULE was turned off or failed. Please update submodules and try again.")
endif()

add_subdirectory(external/glfw)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
                PUBLIC .
)

set(BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES filesystem regex)
#add_subdirectory(external/boost EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                PUBLIC external/glfw/include
                PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
                PUBLIC external/glfw/src
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PUBLIC
                glfw
                ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)

This is my batch file for building
cd "C:/Users/[USERNAME]/source/repos/Madeline
Cmake -S . -B out/build -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF
cd "out/build"
make
pause
start Madeline.exe

and my error log is
Cmake -S . -B out/build -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1706 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1707 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1709 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1710 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1711 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1743 ] BOOST_ROOT = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1744 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_85_0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1745 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1746 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1747 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1748 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1836 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1876 ] Boost_VERSION = "1.85.0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1877 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.85.0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1878 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "108500"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1879 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1880 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "85"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1881 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1882 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1906 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1907 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-mgw13" (guessed)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1943 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2021 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2025 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2026 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/../lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2087 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/../lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- Found Boost: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_85_0 (found suitable version "1.85.0", minimum required is "1.85")
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Including Win32 support
-- Looking for dinput.h
-- Looking for dinput.h - found
-- Looking for xinput.h
-- Looking for xinput.h - found
-- Configuring done (13.3s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/[USERNAME]/source/repos/Madeline/out/build

C:\Users\[USERNAME]\source\repos\Madeline>cd "out/build"

C:\Users\[USERNAME]\source\repos\Madeline\out\build>make
[  4%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.obj
[  8%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.obj
[ 12%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.obj
[ 16%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.obj
[ 20%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/platform.c.obj
[ 24%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/vulkan.c.obj
[ 28%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.obj
[ 32%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.obj
[ 36%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/osmesa_context.c.obj
[ 40%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/null_init.c.obj
[ 44%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/null_monitor.c.obj
[ 48%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/null_window.c.obj
[ 52%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/null_joystick.c.obj
[ 56%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_module.c.obj
[ 60%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_time.c.obj
[ 64%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_thread.c.obj
[ 68%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_init.c.obj
[ 72%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj
[ 76%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj
[ 80%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj
[ 84%] Building C object external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj
[ 88%] Linking C static library libglfw3.a
[ 88%] Built target glfw
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Madeline.dir/src/Skeleton/main.cpp.obj
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Madeline.dir/src/MCAD/Logger/Logging.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable Madeline.exe
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::core::get()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::core::add_global_attribute(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::core::get()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::core::add_global_attribute(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6214attribute_nameC1EPKc[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6214attribute_nameC1EPKc]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const*)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt627sources12basic_loggerIcNS2_6loggerENS2_19single_thread_modelEED2Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt627sources12basic_loggerIcNS2_6loggerENS2_19single_thread_modelEED2Ev]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_set::~attribute_set()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEEC1Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEEC1Ev]+0x1a): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes7counterIjEC1Ejj[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes7counterIjEC1Ejj]+0x21): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt627sources12basic_loggerIcNS2_6loggerENS2_19single_thread_modelEEC2Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt627sources12basic_loggerIcNS2_6loggerENS2_19single_thread_modelEEC2Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::core::get()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt627sources12basic_loggerIcNS2_6loggerENS2_19single_thread_modelEEC2Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt627sources12basic_loggerIcNS2_6loggerENS2_19single_thread_modelEEC2Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_set::attribute_set()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes7counterIjE4implD0Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes7counterIjE4implD0Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator delete(void*, unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEE4implD0Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEE4implD0Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator delete(void*, unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEE4impl9get_valueEv[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEE4impl9get_valueEv]+0x1b): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEE4impl9get_valueEv[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes11basic_clockINS2_17local_time_traitsEE4impl9get_valueEv]+0x83): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator delete(void*, unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes20make_attribute_valueIRjEENS1_15attribute_valueEOT_[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes20make_attribute_valueIRjEENS1_15attribute_valueEOT_]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes20attribute_value_implIjED0Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes20attribute_value_implIjED0Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator delete(void*, unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes20attribute_value_implINS_10posix_time5ptimeEED0Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6210attributes20attribute_value_implINS_10posix_time5ptimeEED0Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator delete(void*, unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text+0x715): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::text_file_backend::set_open_handler(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::light_function<void (std::ostream&)> const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text+0x7ab): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::text_file_backend::set_close_handler(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::light_function<void (std::ostream&)> const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text+0x7d8): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::core::get()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text+0x815): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::core::add_sink(boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::sink> const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text+0xa62): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::text_file_backend::set_file_collector(boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::file::collector> const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux17once_block_sentryD1Ev[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux17once_block_sentryD1Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::once_block_sentry::rollback()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux17once_block_sentry8executedEv[_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux17once_block_sentry8executedEv]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::once_block_sentry::enter_once_block() const'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6211expressions3tag7message8get_nameEv[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6211expressions3tag7message8get_nameEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::default_attribute_names::message()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6211expressions3tag8smessage8get_nameEv[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6211expressions3tag8smessage8get_nameEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::default_attribute_names::message()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost19thread_specific_ptrINS_3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE18formatting_contextEED1Ev[_ZN5boost19thread_specific_ptrINS_3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE18formatting_contextEED1Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, void (*)(void (*)(void*), void*), void (*)(void*), void*, bool)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks4file3aux14make_collectorINS_9parameter3aux18flat_like_arg_listIJNS7_19flat_like_arg_tupleINS1_8keywords3tag9max_filesENS7_15tagged_argumentISC_KiEESt17integral_constantIbLb1EEEENS9_INSB_14min_free_spaceENSD_ISJ_SE_EESH_EENS9_INSB_6targetENSD_ISM_A36_KcEESH_EENS9_INSB_8max_sizeENSD_ISR_SE_EESH_EEEEEEENS_10shared_ptrINS3_9collectorEEERKT_[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks4file3aux14make_collectorINS_9parameter3aux18flat_like_arg_listIJNS7_19flat_like_arg_tupleINS1_8keywords3tag9max_filesENS7_15tagged_argumentISC_KiEESt17integral_constantIbLb1EEEENS9_INSB_14min_free_spaceENSD_ISJ_SE_EESH_EENS9_INSB_6targetENSD_ISM_A36_KcEESH_EENS9_INSB_8max_sizeENSD_ISR_SE_EESH_EEEEEEENS_10shared_ptrINS3_9collectorEEERKT_]+0xfb): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::file::aux::make_collector(boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux12basic_formatIcEC1EPKc[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux12basic_formatIcEC1EPKc]+0x40): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::format_description<char> boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::parse_format<char>(char const*, char const*)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks17text_file_backend9constructINS_9parameter3aux18flat_like_arg_listIJNS6_19flat_like_arg_tupleINS1_8keywords3tag9file_nameENS6_15tagged_argumentISB_A22_KcEESt17integral_constantIbLb1EEEENS8_INSA_13rotation_sizeENSC_ISJ_KiEESH_EEEEEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks17text_file_backend9constructINS_9parameter3aux18flat_like_arg_listIJNS6_19flat_like_arg_tupleINS1_8keywords3tag9file_nameENS6_15tagged_argumentISB_A22_KcEESt17integral_constantIbLb1EEEENS8_INSA_13rotation_sizeENSC_ISJ_KiEESH_EEEEEEEvRKT_]+0x217): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::text_file_backend::construct(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, std::_Ios_Openmode, unsigned long long, boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::light_function<bool ()> const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::auto_newline_mode, bool, bool)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail13sp_ms_deleterINS_3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks17text_file_backendEE7destroyEv[_ZN5boost6detail13sp_ms_deleterINS_3log11v2s_mt_nt625sinks17text_file_backendEE7destroyEv]+0x2b): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sinks::text_file_backend::~text_file_backend()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost10filesystem4path9assign_opclIcEEvPKT_S6_PKSt7codecvtIwc9_MbstatetE[_ZNK5boost10filesystem4path9assign_opclIcEEvPKT_S6_PKSt7codecvtIwc9_MbstatetE]+0x44): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet> const*)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6221value_visitor_invokerINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS6_IwS7_IwESaIwEEEEENS1_16fallback_to_noneEEclINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS8_S9_EEEEEEEENS1_17visitation_resultERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setET_[_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6221value_visitor_invokerINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS6_IwS7_IwESaIwEEEEENS1_16fallback_to_noneEEclINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS8_S9_EEEEEEEENS1_17visitation_resultERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setET_]+0x31): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name) const'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6221value_visitor_invokerINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS6_IwS7_IwESaIwEEEEENS1_16fallback_to_noneEEclINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS8_S9_EEEEEEEENS1_17visitation_resultERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setET_[_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6221value_visitor_invokerINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS6_IwS7_IwESaIwEEEEENS1_16fallback_to_noneEEclINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS8_S9_EEEEEEEENS1_17visitation_resultERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setET_]+0x41): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_value_set::end() const'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6221value_visitor_invokerINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS6_IwS7_IwESaIwEEEEENS1_16fallback_to_noneEEclINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS8_S9_EEEEEEEENS1_17visitation_resultERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setET_[_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6221value_visitor_invokerINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS6_IwS7_IwESaIwEEEEENS1_16fallback_to_noneEEclINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS8_S9_EEEEEEEENS1_17visitation_resultERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setET_]+0xfe): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux24type_sequence_dispatcherINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS7_IwS8_IwESaIwEEEEEE19get_dispatching_mapINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS9_SA_EEEEEEEEPKSt4pairINS_9typeindex14stl_type_indexEPvEv[_ZN5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt623aux24type_sequence_dispatcherINS_3mpl7vector2INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS7_IwS8_IwESaIwEEEEEE19get_dispatching_mapINS1_9binder1stINS1_10output_funERNS1_11expressions3aux10stream_refINS1_24basic_formatting_ostreamIcS9_SA_EEEEEEEEPKSt4pairINS_9typeindex14stl_type_indexEPvEv]+0x186): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::once_block_sentry::commit()'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6215value_extractorINS_10posix_time5ptimeENS1_16fallback_to_noneEvEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE[_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6215value_extractorINS_10posix_time5ptimeENS1_16fallback_to_noneEvEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE]+0x2d): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name) const'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6215value_extractorINS_10posix_time5ptimeENS1_16fallback_to_noneEvEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE[_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6215value_extractorINS_10posix_time5ptimeENS1_16fallback_to_noneEvEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE]+0x3d): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_value_set::end() const'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\Madeline.dir/objects.a(Logging.cpp.obj):Logging.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6215value_extractorINS_10posix_time5ptimeENS1_16fallback_to_noneEvEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE[_ZNK5boost3log11v2s_mt_nt6215value_extractorINS_10posix_time5ptimeENS1_16fallback_to_noneEvEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE]+0xef): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name const&)'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
~~~~~ LOG ENDED BECUASE OF CHARACTER LIMIT ~~~~~

I've tried every stackoverflow answer I could find about linking Boost, and I still cant find anything. Please help, I've been trying this for a week. I've reinstalled Boost 3 times and I've checked a lot of syntax that is supposed to fix this, but I cant find anything to fix it.

"I've tried every stackoverflow answer" - Not sure what have you tried, but searching for the error in boost::log namespace reveals many questions and answers which suggest to link at least log library of the Boost. See e.g. that answer.
